# Accessing SelectListItem Value and Text in a Javascript script MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

I am building a dynamic web form (meaning additional rows of fields can be added as needed) with a searchable drop down list as one of the fields with the entries populated from a database. I am making the drop down searchable via select2, and I'm adding new rows to the form using javascript append. I have a <SelectListItem>ViewBag element that I am trying to use to populate the dropdown box in each row. Currently, I am able to make as many entries as there are items in the List element, but I am unable to access the Value and Text properties for the items to populate the drop down. I am able to access the Selected property.

My Controller looks like the following:

```
//Populate program search dropdown from DB
                List<SelectListItem> ls = new List<SelectListItem>();
                var lm = entities.SCInnovationProject;
                foreach (var temp in lm)
                {

                    ls.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = temp.ProjectName, Value = temp.SCInnovationProjectId.ToString() });
                }
                ViewBag.projectSearch = ls;
```

The Javascript portion of my View looks like:

```
<script>
    var counter = 1;
    $(function () {
        $('#add').click(function () {
            $('<tr id="tablerow' + counter + '">' +
                '<td>' +
                '<select class="catch form-control" id="dependentProjectID_' + counter + '_" name="dependentProjectID[' + counter + ']"><option value="">Select dependent project</option>' +
                @{foreach (var item in ViewBag.projectSearch)
                    {
                        @:'<option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>' +
                    }
                 }
                '</select>' +
                '</td>' +
                '</tr>').appendTo('#submissionTable');
                $('.catch').select2();
                counter++;
                return false;
        });
    });
    function removeTr(index) {
        if (counter > 1) {
            $('#tablerow' + index).remove();
            counter--;
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

If I switch out "item.Value" and "item.Text" for "item.Selected" the code will execute and display "False"s in the drop down list. If someone could please enlighten me as to how I can access the "Value" and "Text" fields to populate the drop downs, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your codes, it seems there is no problem on my side.

View:

```
<button id="btn">Test</button>

<div id="submissionTable"></div>
```

Scripts:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $("#btn").click(function () {
        var counter = 1;
        $('<tr id="tablerow' + counter + '">' +
            '<td>' +
            '<select class="catch form-control" id="dependentProjectID_' + counter + '_" name="dependentProjectID[' + counter + ']"><option value="">Select dependent project</option>' +
            @{foreach (var item in ViewBag.projectSearch)
                {
                    @:'<option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>' +
                }
             }
            '</select>' +
            '</td>' +
            '</tr>').appendTo('#submissionTable');
            $('.catch').select2();
            counter++;
            return false;

    })
</script>
```

Controller:

```
List<SelectListItem> ls = new List<SelectListItem>();
ls.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "A" });
ls.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "B" });
ls.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "C" });
ViewBag.projectSearch = ls;
```

Result:

[image]

You may debug to check the value in the ViewBag, and if you use `item.Value` and `item.Text`, is there any error messages?

Comment: Thanks so much for you feedback! I looked in the generated javascript and it turns out the problem is some of the entries in the SQL database which were used to populate the drop down list contained new line characters! This separated the `+'...' across multiple lines which made the javascript fail. I added in a string replacement to remove these when I build the SelectListItems in the controller and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use *javascript* to populate the table. You need to combine ***html*** with ***Razor*** for these purposes. I believe this is what you tried to do

```
<table>
    @for (var i = 0; i < @ViewBag.projectSearch.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr id=@string.Format("tablerow{0}", @i)>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList("dependentProjectID_" + i, (List<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.projectSearch, "Select dependent project", null)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: For populating the initial row, this is correct, but because the table needs to add copies of that row dynamically. For this dynamic function, you need to use javascript. An alternative approach I have tried is to use javascript to copy the inital row, but this produces problems due to the unique ID for each drop down box required by select2. I know you can use a string editor in javascript to change the IDs, but it is tedious and doesn't seem like the most sensible solution.